# Get URL of error page in global.asax's Application_OnError

Tags: asp.net, error-handling, global-asax, application-onerror

I have an ASP.NET application where I am tracking my application level errors using Global.asax `On_Error` method. I will send an email to my id when there is some error happened in the site (i.e.: when the `Application_Error` being invoked). Now from my Global.asax's `Application_OnError` event, how can I get the URL of the page where this error was raised?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use Request.Url

Answer (score 4):

You can use:

```
HttpContext.Current.Request.Url
```

Answer (score 2):

Will Request.RawUrl work?